# I am trying to merge two JsonObjects in java

Tags: java, json

I have JsonObjects fields,obj2.I am trying to add fields in both the objects.

```
 JsonObject fields=commonfields.getJsonObject("fields");
 JsonObjet additional=jo.getJsonObject("zas");  
               fields.put(additional);
```

Expected outcome should be merged fields of two objects.I am getting errors.

Comment: Can you post the errors? you have a typo in JsonObjet

Comment: Which package is your JsonObject from? `javax.json.JsonObject` implements `Map<String,JsonValue>` so you can just call `fields.putAll(additional);` like you can with Maps.

Comment: io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject. i am using this library. PutAll didn't work for me.getting cannot find the symbol error

Comment: `Expected outcome should be merged fields of two objects. I am getting errors.` Could you share a small sample of the two input objects, expected output object, and specifically what errors you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

For `io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject`, you can use `mergeIn` method.

```java
       JsonObject fields  = new JsonObject();
        fields.putString("a", "1");
        fields.putBoolean("b", false);
        
        JsonObject additional  = new JsonObject();
        additional.putString("c", "1");
        additional.putBoolean("d", false);
        
        fields.mergeIn(additional);
        
        System.out.println(fields);`
```

`javax.json.JsonObject` provides `putAll` method, as it implements `Map` interface.

For other types of `JsonObject`, which do not implements `Map` interface you can parse over keys and explicitly put key, value pair in `JsonObject`.